# Where I can find a guide to the laws of the United States?

Tags: usa, legal, alcohol

Where I can find a guide to the laws of the United States? Many laws are different between **Brazil** and **United States**:

- Minimum age to drink alcoholic drink. in Brazil 18 years.
- In Brazil is allowed to drink in public

Comment: US:  Drinking age is 21.  Whether you can drink in public is a matter of **local** law.

Comment: @LorenPechtel the drinking age is a matter of state law; it just happens that the states all have the same age limit.

Comment: @phoog It's not "just happens"--the feds applied a lot of pressure to establish the drinking age at 21.  Besides, how it came about isn't what he's asking.

Comment: @LorenPechtel For that matter, he's not asking what the laws are; he's asking where to find a source summarizing these laws

Answer (score 4):

(This is not legal advice.)

**Wikipedia** normally provides an adequate summary of countries' laws and regulations in common areas of interest to travelers, such as motorcycle helmets and drinking age.

For example, a [Google search for [drinking age in usa]](http://google.com/webhp?q=drinking+age+in+usa) returned the ["Legal drinking age" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_drinking_age#Americas) as its first result. A similar page exists for drinking in public, namely ["United States open container laws"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_open_container_laws).